# Modal not disapearing if user likes FB page

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I know this question already got asked and I looked into those answers but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it in my own code. On a previous question a kind gentleman helped me out with a beginning: [Overlaying closing button ontop of facebook like button but keep functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635805/overlaying-closing-button-ontop-of-facebook-like-button-but-keep-functionality)

But I can't seem to get the code to work. What I want is that the modal I display when the page loads to disapear automaticly if the site detects that you already liked the facebook page. But keep it untill they like it if they dont already. I'm hosting the site locally atm but it's going live soon.

Heres the code I got:

```
        .fb_iframe_widget span
        {        
            overflow: initial !important;
        }

        .fb_iframe_widget iframe
        {        
            width: 340px !important;
            height: 500px !important;    
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- facebook -->
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>

    <script>

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
        {
            FB.init(
            {
                appId      : '202822426829643',
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v2.8'
            });
            FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

            FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function(a, b)
            {
                document.getElementById('id00').style.display='none';
            })

        };

        (function(d, s, id) 
        {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=202822426829643";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>

    <!-- facebook -->
    <div id="id00" style="z-index: 3; padding-top: 100px; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)">

        <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-top w3-card-2">

            <header class="w3-container w3-yellow">

                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id00').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>

                <h3><b>like kace op facebook om onze adventskalender te gebruiken</b></h3>

            </header>

            <div class="w3-container w3-padding-32">

                <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/we.are.kace/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="340" data-height="70" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/we.are.kace/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/we.are.kace/">KACE</a></blockquote></div>

            </div>  

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Like gating in any way, shape or form is not allowed by Facebook any more. You are not supposed to show different content to the user based on whether or not they liked your page.

Comment: what CBroe said. Also, it is not possible anyway. you would need to authorize the user with the user_likes permission, but you don´t get that one approved just for checking if the user liked your page already.

Comment: Alright thanks for the feedback guys